# Accumulative return value for non-static variable?

Tags: c

I ran into unexpected behavior with a function I wrote to compute the average point for a set of 3D points.

```
static inline Point3d
average_vertex_position( Vertex vertices[], int nPoints )
{
  Point3d average = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }; // Must be there to avoid accumulation
  Point3d point;
  int i;

  for ( i = 0; i < nPoints; i++ )
  {
    point = vertices[i].position;
    average.x += point.x;
    average.y += point.y;
    average.z += point.z;
  }

  average.x /= (double) nPoints;
  average.y /= (double) nPoints;
  average.z /= (double) nPoints;

  return average;
}



// ...
Point3d average;
// ...
for ( j = i; j < nVertices; j++ )
{
  // ...
  average = average_vertex_position( vertices, nVertices );
  // ...
}
```

For each iteration the return value of `average_vertex_position` would accumulate unless I added explicitly the initialization `Point3d average = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };`.

If the previous return value was `Point3d( 10, 0, 20 )` and the next run should have returned `Point3d( 20, 10, 0 )` it would instead return an accumulated result `Point3d( 30, 10, 20 )`.

Originally I had just `Point3d average;` assuming all the member values (`double` values) would be initialized to 0.0. I also assumed `average` would be in this initial state between each call. I don't understand why I need to explicitly initialize it?

I trimmed out the code I didn't think was relevant - but I could be wrong, in which case I'll update if it doesn't hold enough information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is normal with `auto` variables - they are not initialized to 0 if not explicitly stated.

The fact that the old values are reused is pure coincidence, as you don't have any other function calls in-between. If you would have them, the memory at the given stack position would be overwritten and your values were different.

Comment: Well there was something I'd missed out on when I was reading up on C and variables. I'd thought `int` and `double` was always initiated to 0. Clearly explicit initiation is the safest.

Comment: Is it possible to define the default values of a `struct` in its definition - or do I have to do it each time I create a variable like in the example I posted?

Comment: @thomthom where did you read that? because that's one more place to burn to the ground for spreading baseless bullshit.

Comment: It's probably just a misunderstanding on my behalf that they implicitly was initiated to 0. I'm very green to C - emerging from scripting languages like Ruby, PHP and JS. Looking back now I think it said that global and static where initiated to 0 - while automatic are not. I didn't realize "normal" variables where called "automatic". Quite a n00b mistake indeed.